# how to use 'if' condition inside the cursor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to loop set of datas. The datas are actually table names. The table names will be stored in temperary variable while looping . So I need to use the value of temperary variable inside if statement. But it shows

> Must declare variable

```
DECLARE TBL_Cur CURSOR
FOR ( select name from sysobjects where name like 'tbl_flat%')
DECLARE @TblName NVARCHAR(MAX);
OPEN TBL_Cur
FETCH NEXT FROM TBL_Cur INTO @TblName
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
if(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM @TblName ) >0
  do somthing
end if
CLOSE TBL_Cur
DEALLOCATE TBL_Cur
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Please show what you've tried

Comment: you need to `DECLARE` the variable, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx

Comment: @charu you need to add your sql statements in your question, other wise how can we help you?

Comment: It shows error in this line 'if(SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM @TblName ) >0'

Comment: `@TblName` is not a table variable, it's a string. You can't just use table *name* variables in a `select` statement.

Comment: How can i use the table name ? I need to delete that table if count greater than 0

Comment: You cannot use a variable in place of a table.  You need to build up the SQL using a NVARCHAR variable and then run it using dynamic SQL ([sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188001.aspx))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code. Instead of PRINT, you can perform the actual operation
According to my understaindng, you are retrieving all the table names in a cursor. If each of these table has records, then you want to perform some action. I used dynamic query with a a parameter, to retrieve the number of records. The output parameter return back the count to the local variable

```
DECLARE @TblName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SQL  NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @count  INT;
DECLARE TBL_Cur CURSOR
FOR ( select name from sysobjects where name like 'tbl_flat%')
OPEN TBL_Cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM TBL_Cur INTO @TblName

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
  SET @SQL = N'SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @TblName
  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@count INT OUT', @count OUT
  IF(@count >0)
  BEGIN
      PRINT @TblName + N' : ' + STR(@count)
      --Do your actions here
  END
  FETCH NEXT FROM TBL_Cur INTO @TblName
END
CLOSE TBL_Cur
DEALLOCATE TBL_Cur
```

Comment: OP is not after the length of the table name... they're after the number of rows in the table

Comment: Just edited my answer, hope this is what you are trying to achieve